# Tategaki (japanese vertical writing) in iOS apps

Tags: ios, user-controls, ruby-characters

Is there a user control (standard or third-party) for iOS that allows to display vertical text of East Asian languages? I also need to display a ruby characters (furigana/reading aid) near the text. Result should look like this http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/3262/img0088xa.jpg (japanese iBooks screenshot)

Comment: At this time, you may need to use Core Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time you will need Core Text or a view using Core Text.
Github search fails but googling in Japanese wins. 
http://cocoadays-info.blogspot.jp/2012/01/coretexttextview-lccoretext.html
Blog article in Japanese on this 
https://github.com/novi/LTCoreText

Should do the trick.

Too bad github search doesn't find it.

Google translate may or may not help. I've forked it just now and will translate the read me soon.

Also found https://github.com/hokuron/CTRVerticalTextView
Though it seems fairly unfinished and it's owner's blog seems down. 
A Japanese site has this nifty page of bookmarks on the topic. 
http://b.hatena.ne.jp/Watson/iOS/CoreText/

Comment: Project code is pretty clean and intelligible. (thanks Cocoa!)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these projects right now. Sorry for late answer.

Comment: No worries. I was curious myself. And very interested to learn more on this implementation.

Comment: Okay, I've checked both projects and ready to give response. In short: LTCoreText looks very heavy for me. It depends on DTCoreText, which also needs DTFoundation. But in comparison with CTRVerticalTextView, LTCoreText doesn't have any advantages for my tasks. I don't need multi-column layout, HTML-markup and inline images displaying. So I think that I should learn more about CoreText and make something like CTRVerticalTextView by myself. Thanks for directing me to this.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. These may be helpful references when you get into the thick of it. Managing Core Text layout can get painful quickly. In this case, handling font substitution for glyphs that are not in the font in use is one of the points I do not yet know if Core Text handles. Anway, hope this is of some use.